# Ruby-Instagram api form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to be able to type the latitude and longitude and it renders into the method and renders the page.

For example, in my controller I have:

```
def index       
  @instagram = Instagram.media_search("39.78172130000001", "-89.6501481")
end
```

It generates a list of instagram photos in that area based on those coordinates, of course. But I want to make a form where I enter in 2 parameters and it generates itself. If that make sense.

What I have:
http://postimg.org/image/j6rjwx4sx/

Also, sorry if this is worded strangely. It sounds correct in my head, I just suck at wording things.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to read the Rails Guides, perhaps starting with [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html). It describes how data entered into form fields is received by the controller in the `params` hash.

Comment: I've reviewed my book plenty. The thing about it is, a link isn't generated in the address bar. It's 'internal' if you will. It accepts the parameter, but doesn't make it visible. Also thank you

Comment: @Cortland What to do you mean by "a link isn't generated in the address bar"?
please elaborate and try to provide some code snippet.

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal the page renders 'localhost:3000/instagram', which is the page with the images. It doesn't have the Lat or Lon in the address bar, along with the /instagram is what I meant. I want to be able to enter the Lat and Lon in a form and get back the instagram page. You can take a look at this to better understand me: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/Instagram/Client/Media#media_search-instance_method
It takes the ("lat", "lon"). A form that takes those 2 parameters.

Comment: I can't tell without seeing your view code, but I'm guessing either the form is using the POST method (in which case form data is passed in the HTTP request body, not the URL—read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)) or your form fields don't have `name` attributes.

Comment: @Jordan This is sample of what it looks like. http://s24.postimg.org/4nkevibo5/photo.jpg
I want it to take the 2 parameters from the method Instagram.media_search("lat", "lon") and replace the "lat" and "lon".